# could not open file /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/info

Tags: sound, proc

if I start sonic-pi on my ubuntu system, I get the following error:

```
[GUI] - could not open file /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/info
```

In fact the whole directory pcm0p doesn't exist. This is as deep as I can dive into the proc tree:

```
$ ls /proc/asound/card0/
codec#0  eld#0.1   eld#0.11  eld#0.13  eld#0.15  eld#0.3  eld#0.5  eld#0.7  eld#0.9  pcm10p  pcm12p  pcm7p  pcm9p
eld#0.0  eld#0.10  eld#0.12  eld#0.14  eld#0.2   eld#0.4  eld#0.6  eld#0.8  id       pcm11p  pcm3p   pcm8p
```

Any comments on how I can resolve this, are highly welcome.

Here, the description of my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux media 5.13.0-30-generic #33~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 7 14:25:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Some additional notes:

Maybe this has something to do, that I have some sound devices in my system. I have the onboard sound device of my motherboard and I guess also my Nvidia RTX 2070 has a sound device on board. But I would really want to use my onboard sound, since my Nvidia Card is just reserved for machine learning and all sound goes through my onboard sound card.

Maybe this helps:

```
juergen@media:~/tmp$ cat /proc/asound/devices 
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 1- 3]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 1- 7]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0- 7]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 1- 8]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 1- 9]: digital audio playback
  8: [ 1- 0]: hardware dependent
  9: [ 0- 8]: digital audio playback
 10: [ 0- 9]: digital audio playback
 11: [ 0-10]: digital audio playback
 12: [ 0-11]: digital audio playback
 13: [ 0-12]: digital audio playback
 14: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
 15: [ 1]   : control
 16: [ 0]   : control
 17: [ 2- 0]: digital audio playback
 18: [ 2- 0]: digital audio capture
 19: [ 2- 1]: digital audio playback
 20: [ 2- 2]: digital audio capture
 21: [ 2- 0]: hardware dependent
 22: [ 2]   : control
 33:        : timer
```

I saw, that pcm0p exists here (for card2 instead of card0):

```
/proc/asound/card2/pcm0p
```

Not sure now if I should use `/proc/asound/card2/pcm0p` or `/proc/asound/card0/pcm3p` and how I could make sonic-pi use any of these two.

Comment: That is a kernel version not the version of the OS. What is the version of Ubuntu OS you are using?

Comment: It's 20.04.4. Isn't the proc file system created by the kernel?